# How do GET JSON from a website cross domain using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, get, jsonp

I am trying to access a json file from this site using javascript.

http://us.battle.net/auction-data/a6b6ca548431e1202e4248ccf28fd4ad/auctions.json

I understand that I cannot request json cross domain because of some privacy policy. The other way would be jsonp but I am not sure how to do that.

My question is, since blizzard made these api free access to the public but its in json, how would I access this?

Comment: You would first have to figure out if the api supports jsonp. (you should refer to the api's documentation) If it doesn't, you are sol and will have to instead get the data using a server-side technology of your choice.

Comment: https://github.com/Blizzard/api-wow-docs

Comment: It states that it uses restful api. What does this mean?

Comment: an api being restful doesn't mean it does or doesn't support jsonp. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: SO how do you suggest I get this data? I've been trying all day and still no luck =/

Comment: Well, the docs don't mention anything about jsonp, so it's safe to assume it doesn't. *"If it doesn't, you are sol and will have to instead get the data using a server-side technology of your choice."* in other words, php, node.js, asp.net, etc. anything that isn't client-side.